# SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I hope someone can help me with this. I have differente projects (websites) in Visual Studio 2010. Today when I try to expand one of the databases in the data connections of the server explorer, I get a window with this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

The situation occurs in ALL my projects. I suppose this happens because I installed Kaspersky 2012 yesterday. Please I need help.

Comment: I can easily imagine that Kaspersky interfers with the network connection Visual Studio is trying to open to connect to the database. Uninstall it or set up a rule that allows that connection. Where's your SQL Server anyway, on your local machine or on a different one?

Answer (score 2):

May be installing Kaspersky stopped SQL Server service.
Type `services.msc` in run dialog box to open services panel .
Make sure SQL Server service has status as **Started** .
If not , right click on SQL Server and select start.

Of course this is if you are using Windows .

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with your firewall. Here is something you can do to remove this error:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Comment: hi pinal , please visit stackoverflow.com more often , your expertise much much required , i think with your knowledge you are the Jon Skeets of SQL Server